# Implementing a cropping/trimming layer in a convolutional neural net in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

Currently I'm doing cropping prior to training my model. That means I also have to make it a separate step when inferring which isn't ideal. Are there are any tensorflow/keras implementations of a cropping layer?

If not, is there a reason one shouldn't do it as part of the neural net?

Answer (score 0):

In tensorflow, you can crop a tensor by slicing like you would do in `numpy`, e.g. `t_cropped = t[:,10:20,::-1,...]`. Information on this notation can be found on the documentation of [`tf.strided_slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice), which is *in fine* called by slicing.

If you goal is to implemant random cropping prior to feeding your network, [`tf.random_crop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_crop) is the dedicated tensorflow operation for that.